# How to Read Vector File and Write Only Indexes with Criteria

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I wrote a code that reads a file containing a list of vectors and writes in another file the indexes + 1 of the values that contain Zeros.

**Example:**

input.csv

```
0,0,1,0,1
1,1,1,0,0
0,1,0,1,0
1,0,1,0,1
0,0,1,1,0
```

result.csv:

```
1,2,4
4,5
1,3,5
2,4
1,2,5
```

Below is the code, but it is giving error:

```
import numpy as np

with open("c:\\input.csv","r") as csv_file, open("c:\\result.csv","w") as output:
    for line in csv_file:
        x = np.array(line)
        output.write(np.flatnonzero(x==0)+1)
```

Result:

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'ravel'
```

However, when I write the code without using a vector list in a file, the code works normally. See below:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0,0,1,0,1]) 
print(np.flatnonzero(x==0)+1) # Index + 1 -> contain Zeros
```

Result: `[1 2 4]`

What am I doing wrong in the first code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're reading is a string, "0,0,1,0,1\n".  numpy does not know how to translate that.  It created an array of 5 string objects.  Try this.

```
  for line in csv_file:
    x = np.array(list(int(k) for k in line.strip().split(',')))
```

Comment: Tim, output.write (np.flatnonzero (x == 0) +1) is giving the following error ->
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not numpy.ndarray

Comment: It's true.  You can't write an integer array as text output.  You have to format it, basically doing the opposite of what I did to convert strings to integers.  BTW, if each line has a different number of fields, it's not a CSV file.

Comment: Tim, at the end, the CSV output will have the same number of fields. This data was just an example. How would this formatting of the Matrix (Vector) be given to a string before the output to the text file (Data Type Cast)?

Comment: You should be able to figure this out.  `y = np.flatnonzero(x==0)+1` / 
   `output.write(','.join(str(i) for i in y))`

Comment: Tim, perfect, my friend. Just a correction. I needed to put the Newline concatenated to generate the vector lines, because they were all concatenating together in a single line. Update to: output.write(' '.join(str(i) for i in y)+'\n') . You have a lot of knowledge about Python and numpy. Show me some good book about Numpy and Python.

Comment: I should have thought about the newline.  That's the diff between `print` and `output.write`.  I'm sure there must be a Numpy book, but I don't know it.  Numpy tries to do everything Matlab can do, so even Matlab doc can sometimes help.